# GacDeployment does not show any results

Tags: event-receivers, feature, solution-package, solution-deployment, gac

following scenario. I have a structure that looks as follows:

**WebApplication** (App) --> **SiteCollection** (SiteCol) --> **Site** (Site) --> **WebSite** (Web) --> **List**

I developed an eventreceiver which should be applied to the one specific list. Therefor I set the **Scope** of the Feature to **Site**. In the according "Elements.xml" plus in the receivers-tag I set the ListUrl as follows:

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Site/Web/Lists/List">
```

After that I deploy the .wsp via *SharePoint Management Shell* using the following statement:

```
install-spsolution -identity MyReceiver.wsp -gacdeployment
```

As the methods in my Receiver did not seem to be triggered I took a look into *SharePoint Manager*. There I could not find my EventReceiver, above all not in the List.
Still the .wsp seems to be deployed. I can see that using *Management Shell* and it is also listed in the *Solutions*-Treeview in *SharePoint Manager*. Also I can see the feature being activated in the *Site Features*-list, also in *SharePoint Manager*.

This lets me assume that I either picked the wrong scope or did not use the right **ListUrl**. Of course overlooking some other issue is always another possibility.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `Scope` to `Web` and use `<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/List">`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct list url in `ListUrl="Lists/List"`. Note that List Url can be different from List Title.

Comment: I am 100% positive

Comment: When installing the .wsp in Shell, can I specify the web it should be activated for or deployed to?

Comment: Wsp is deployed either globally or for a particular web application.  It is the feature which then needs to be activated at web level in your case.

Comment: Also when I try to deploy it over central administration I can't choose a Web-application as deployment target. Instead I can only deploy it globally.

Comment: this is what actually solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909045/how-to-deploy-a-feature-to-web-application-level (Please include this into your awnser and I will accept it!)

Comment: The referred post may have solved your issue but I don't see any similarity between the two questions.